# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception

Tags: c#

I have  code written in C# on a Windows7 and VS2010, 32 bit using .Net 3.5 and it is runing without any problem, now I converted it to 64 bit using .Net 4.0 but I got an error when my code call CloseHandle.

ERROR - CloseHandle
System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception.

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (byte* p = readBuffer)
    {
         IntPtr intPtr = (IntPtr)p;
         this.ReadFile(ref sourceFile, (ulong)buffer_size, intPtr, ref nNumBytesRead);

         if (intPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
         {
             try
             {
                 FunctionSqudf.CloseHandle(intPtr);
             }
             catch (Exception ex)
             {
                  Hardware.LogHardware.Error("CloseHandle", ex);
             }
         }
      }
  }


    [SecuritySafeCritical]
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are calling CloseHandle() with a buffer pointer, not a handle.  This code could never have worked correctly before, apparently you are being reminded about it now when running in 64-bit mode.

Comment: Peter Ritchie      ReadFile will read a file portion from a media   [SecuritySafeCritical]
[DllImport(dllPath, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, ThrowOnUnmappableChar = true)]
        internal static extern UdfResult ReadFile(
            ref  StructSqudf.SQFile openFsObject, 
   [In] ulong numBytesToBeRead,
            IntPtr  buffer, 
   ref ulong numBytesRead);

Comment: Hans Passant, but there was no error in the catch block before ?

Comment: @Khayralla Please edit your question to include the ReadFile declaration you put in the comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `CloseHandle` with a pointer to user memory.  You need to allocate a `HANDLE` in order to close it.  What do you expect `CloseHandle` to close?

Comment: CloseHandle takes a "valid handle to an open object." which would be a pointer.  The real question is what this.ReadFile is returning.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.closehandle

Comment: @Trisped It's not going to be a valid handle if it's a pointer to memory being written to as a block of memory.  Yes a HANDLE is *technically* a pointer; but a pointer to kernel memory, which an app can't write to.

Comment: Correct your answer and I will remove -1.  Your statement "You can't use CloseHandle with a pointer." is incorrect.

Comment: @Tripsed You can't allocate kernel memory anyway... but I've clarified the answer...

Comment: Peter, static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject); so the code is correct, ReadFile will return a valid intPtr to the object ?

Comment: @Khayralla but you're not using the return value from `ReadFile`, you're using the value in `readBuffer`

Comment: @Peter, yes you are right, byte[] readBuffer = new byte[buffer_size] which is not updated in ReadFile. so there is no need to call CLoseHandle ?