# Is there a C# & VB compatible System.Void* in F#? (To close a pointer to nonmanaged Alloc?)

Tags: c#, vb.net, f#, interop, kernel32

```
    [<DllImport("kernel32")>]
    extern bool CloseHandle(System.Void* handle);
    //System.Void also throws same error
    //extern bool CloseHandle(System.Void handle);
```

gives the error:

> 'System.Void' can only be used as 'typeof' in F#

but

```
    extern bool CloseHandle(typeof<System.Void> handle);
```

does not compile. Same error,

> "System.Void can only be used as typeof..."

F# `void*` does compile

```
    extern bool CloseHandle(void* handle);
```

but using it in C# throws a design-time convert error

```
public void CloseBeforeGarbageCollection(IntPtr someAllocIntPtr)
{
    //test unmanaged block
    var result = CloseHandle(someAllocIntPtr.ToPointer());
    return result;
}
```

> 'cannot convert from 'void*' to 'System.IntPtr'

though passing the managed IntPtr will compile

```
//test managed IntPtr
var result = CloseHandle(someAllocIntPtr); //throws error at runtime
```

but when `someAllocIntPtr` is the result of `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, it  throws a runtime exception `External component has thrown an exception.`.
As I understand it, this happens because `someAllocIntPtr` (as the result of Marshal.AllocHGlobal) is technically a managed pointer TO an unmanaged pointer, not the same as a normal IntPtr. This is noted by Peter Ritchie in a reply to his answer here: [System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException (0x80004005): External component has thrown an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12589604/system-runtime-interopservices-sehexception-0x80004005-external-component-has)

The only way to avoid this runtime Exception is to wrap the handle in a `SecureHandle()` subclass, but I think that's against the `ref-ref\out-out` rule on MSDN: [CA1021: Avoid out parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx).
IE, `System.Void* realPointer = someAllocIntPtr.ToPointer()` is the ACTUAL pointer (a reference to an unmanaged pointer), or in other words, `SecureHandle safeHandle = new SecureHandle(someAllocIntPtr)` is actually "*a reference of - **another reference of** - an actual pointer*", and should not be passed with `out` or `ref` keywords, according to the MSDN article.

Comment: Why not use IntPtr?

Comment: `someAllowIntPtr` is a `System.IntPtr`, but its the result of `Marshal.AllocHGlobal`, which is technically a managed pointer to an unmanaged pointer, which is what `IntPtr.ToPointer()` should resolve, but passing the managed IntPtr of nonmanaged memory throws an error at runtime unless its wrapped in a `SecureHandle()` subclass, which seems like it could present reliability issues with interop\externs affording to the ref-ref\out-out rule on MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182131.aspx

Comment: void* is not a valid managed type.  The F# compiler wisely wrote IntPtr to the assembly metadata so you are expected to use IntPtr in your C# program as the error message tells you.  You already have one, someAllocIntPtr.  Do keep in mind that CloseHandle() only accepts a *handle*.  Which is represented as IntPtr or HandleRef or one of the SafeHandle derived class objects in managed code.  "someAlloc" does not exactly sound like a handle.  The odds that you should *ever* use CloseHandle() yourself are minimal, all system objects are wrapped by .NET wrapper classes.

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks! VERY informative!
My motivation for manually closing handles is to force clean up handle leaks which are known to occur in `OpenProcessToken()` with `TOKEN_DUPLICATE` flag (on UAC-enabled machines [with splitTokens])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done a little test in the following way:

In an f# assembly (dll library) I have the following module:

```
module MyWin32
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<DllImport("kernel32")>]
extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

[<DllImport("kernel32")>]
extern IntPtr CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(IntPtr flag, IntPtr procId);
```

In an F# Console Program that has a reference to the above lib I have:

```
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices
open MyWin32

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 

  let handle = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(IntPtr(4), IntPtr(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id))
  printfn "%A" handle
  printfn "%b" (CloseHandle handle)

  // A HGlobal should always be released by FreeHGlobal
  let intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(1024)
  Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtr)
```

And in a C# Console program that references the above lib I have:

```
using System;

namespace CSTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      var handle = MyWin32.CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(new IntPtr(4), new IntPtr(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id));
      Console.WriteLine(handle);
      Console.WriteLine(MyWin32.CloseHandle(handle));

      Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Both the F# and C# test compiles and runs as expeceted. I hope this will help you.

**About void*:**

Changing f# assembly MyWin32 shown above to the following with substution of IntPtr to void* still works for the F# and C# client without any other modfications (The C# metadata code of MyWin32 substitutes void* with IntPtr):

```
module MyWin32
open System
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

[<DllImport("kernel32")>]
extern bool CloseHandle(void* handle);

[<DllImport("kernel32")>]
extern void* CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(IntPtr flag, IntPtr procId);
```

So the conclusion of the above small tests is that you can use void* in F# as a valid substitution for IntPtr.

I think one should only use IntPtr.ToPointer() in an unsafe {} section in C#, as pointers only make sense in unsafe mode in C#.

Comment: Solid example and working solution to my problem. Extra points for `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot` and brevity, but I'm not sure it solves the question of whether the type `System.Void*` can be used in F# for other people who might be looking for that answer.

Comment: @epicTurkey: Please see my addition to the answer (About void*)

Comment: For anyone that missed it (like I did briefly), @HansPassant 's comment on my OP points out that void* is not a valid managed type, and the f#  compiler [wisely] replaces it with IntPtr.